# Local Network sharing

Tags: 14.04

Why I am getting this error when I am trying to share my folder on a network.

[image: Error that I am getting]

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck Guest Access and more steps are below first backup configuration file by typing:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /usr/share/samba/smb.conf.bak
```

Try to edit *sudo vi /usr/share/samba/smb.conf*

```
encrypt passwords = true

usershare owner only = false
```

Also change "security = share" to "security = user" and guest account = nobody
Then restart

```
sudo service smbd restart

sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not helpful to me, brings error that;  /home/joas/Pictures/Screenshot 2016-02-11 05:36:51.png